# Where did my Group Policy templates go?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I was just trying to solve an Office-related problem by importing the [Office 2010 Administrative Template files](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18968) into my ADMX Central Store (`SYSVOL\Policies\PolicyDefinitions`), now all of the "normal" group policy templates are gone.

Why did they disappear and how do I get them back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put the new ADMX files into your Central Store, you most likely created a folder similar to

```
\\domain.example.com\SYSVOL\domain.example.com\Policies\PolicyDefinitions
```

Then, you placed the `.admx` files inside it.

The existence of the **Policies** folder is not an indicator of a previously existing Central Store. By creating the **PolicyDefinitions** you've basically created said Central Store.

When no Central Store exists, the group policy management console will display the group policy templates that are stored **locally** on the machine. These can be found in `%systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions`.

Once a Central Store exists, group policy templates will be loaded exclusively from there, the local policy templates are ignored.

You can now either load them manually when editing a group policy object (Right-click Administrative Templates, Add/remove templates, select the `.admx` files from `%systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions`), or simply [populate your Central Store with the local templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530196.aspx):

> 1. Open a command window: click **Start**, click **Run**, then type **cmd**.
> 2. To copy all the language-neutral ADMX files from your Windows Vista administrative workstation to the central store on your domain controller using the **xcopy** command, type:
>
>    ```
>     xcopy %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions\* %logonserver%\sysvol\%userdnsdomain%\policies\PolicyDefinitions\
>    ```
> 3. To copy all ADMX language resource files from your Windows Vista administrative workstation to the central store on your domain controller using the **xcopy** command, type:
>
>    ```
>     xcopy %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions\EN-US\* %logonserver%\sysvol\%userdnsdomain%\policies\PolicyDefinitions\EN-US\
>    ```

Comment: I am having the same issue as this question. I have copied all of my ADMX files to the central store, but when I go to edit a group policy on the domain controller, I still do not have anything listed under the `Administrative Templates` section. Any ideas?