# How do I import ADMX files for Microsoft Office 2013?

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-office

There is no ADM file (policy template) that I can find for MS Office 2013 so I can't figure out how to get the ADMX files imported to create GPOs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Office 2013 Administrative Template files (ADMX/ADML) and Office Customization Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35554)

There are no ADM files for Office 2010+, you must use the ADMX files. It's usually easiest to place them in a [Central Store for Group Policy Templates](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929841)

**Edit**:
I think you might be trying to edit the local policy of a single machine; which is not recommended. However it does work to extract the ADMX folder, then copy it to `%systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions`. The next time you open `gpedit.msc` you should be able to edit Office settings for the local policy.

Comment: I'm using the Office 2010 ADM files now actually, I imported them via GPMC. I've already downloaded to Office 2013 files you linked me to but I can't seem to figure out how to import them into GPMC as there is no ADM file.

Comment: There's no ADM files because you need to place them in a central store for group policy templates, just like Chris already said. The system's changed from how it used to be.

Comment: @RobM I placed the files in %systemroot%\sysvol\domain\Policies\PolicyDefinitions (did before I posted this actually) but it doesn't appear in GPEdit under Administrative Templates for some reason. Do I need to manually defined the central store location for the templates somehow?

Comment: Note: I'll look at this more closely tomorrow, I may have missed something in the Central Store link Chris S provided.

Comment: I think you left out some details that change the answer a bit, see edit.

Comment: @CrabbyAdmin Which OS are you editing the GPO from?  You're using RSAT for Vista or higher, right?

Comment: @Chris S No, I'm trying to do this via GPO, not locally.

Comment: @jscott - I'm trying to edit the GPOs from one of our DCs running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I'm a little confused I guess. `gpedit.msc` is for editing the local computer policy, not domain policy objects. For domain object you should be running `gpmc.msc`. The location they load the Policy Definitions from varies depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Chris S you're correct. I've been using gpmc.msc and typed in the wrong thing. Good catch.

Comment: @Chris S Sorry for not getting back to this until now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ChrisS Requesting clarification.  When I copy the ADMX Files for Office 2013 in to `$systemroot$\PolicyDefinitions` and start gpmc, the regular Administrative Template entries are removed and I only see Office 2013.  Likewise when I remove the ADMX and re-launch gpmc, i see the old Administrative Template entries, but any GPO's with Office 2013 settings only show the reg keys associated with the policy.  Is there any happy medium to see both Office 2013 ADMX and default Administrative Templates entries?

Comment: More intensive searching to include office 2010 in my results and this article was retrieved: http://serverfault.com/questions/458144/where-did-my-group-policy-templates-go

Comment: If you're using GPMC for a domain you should not be putting ADMX files in your Local Store, they should be in the Central Store.

Answer (score 0):

Populate the Central Store with ADMX Files

There is no user interface for populating the central store in Windows Vista. The following procedure shows how to populate the central store using command line syntax from the domain controller. To populate the central store:

1. Open a command window: Press the Windows logo key + R, and then type cmd.
2. To copy all language-neutral ADMX files (.admx) from your Windows Vista administrative workstation to the central store on your domain controller using the copy command, type:

   ```
   copy  %systemroot% \PolicyDefinitions\*  %logonserver% \sysvol\ %userdnsdomain% \policies\PolicyDefinitions\
   ```
3. To copy all ADMX language-specific resource files (.adml) from your Windows Vista administrative workstation to the central store on your domain controller using the copy command, type:

   ```
   copy  %systemroot% \PolicyDefinitions \ [MUIculture] \*  %logonserver% \sysvol\ %userdnsdomain% \policies\PolicyDefinitions\ [MUIculture] \
   ```

For example, to copy all United States English .adml files, type the following:

```
copy  %systemroot% \PolicyDefinitions\EN-US\*  %logonserver% \sysvol\ %userdnsdomain% \policies\PolicyDefinitions\EN-US\
```